# Change measure results depending on a slicer using Power BI

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, measurement

I'm making a report using Power BI. The data that I'll show is the cummulative amount of a turnover. Inside the data source I've this data.

| Month | Amount | Filter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 17 | Option A |
| 1 | 15 | Option B |
| 1 | 16 | Option C |
| 2 | 12 | Option A |
| 2 | 14 | Option B |
| 2 | 13 | Option C |
| 3 | 17 | Option A |
| 3 | 11 | Option B |
| 3 | 18 | Option C |

I've this on the report:

[image]

For the filter column I'll create a slicer and when there's nothing selected the sum of all the options must be show in the graph, when selected on or multiple only the selections must be shown in the graph.

To create the graph I've created this measure:

```
Cummulative amount = CALCULATE(
    SUM('Turnover'[Amount]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Turnover'),
        'Turnover'[Month] <= MAX('Turnover'[Month])
    )
)
```

In this situation, when I select an option from the filters, the graph doesn't change the data. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also asked it on the Power BI community site and got this answer:

> I think you should use ALLSELECTED instead of ALL for the desired results:
>
> ```
> Commulative amount =  CALCULATE(
>     ALLSELECTED('Turnover'[Amount]),
>     FILTER(
>         ALLSELECTED('Turnover'), 
>         'Turnover'[Month] <= MAX('Turnover'[Month])
>     )
> )
> ```